# Python + BeautifulSoup: Can't seem to scrape the specific data that I want from a website due to the website's formatting

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm a brand new programmer. This is the first program I have ever written, and this is the first post I have ever made on this website.

I am trying to web scrape data for my own personal stock uses and I can't seem to get the proper information to be extracted due to the way the website is formatted. I was wondering if someone could help me. I have tried searching around, but can't find an answer to my problem.

I need the second to last line to be web scraped that reads "3.60/2.56%" but I'm having problems getting to it. I was wondering if maybe there was a way to call a specific line of code from this section.

```
<table class="name-value-pair hide-for-960">
    <tr>
        <td>Beta
            <div class="tooltip">
            <h3>Beta</h3>
            <p>A measure of the volatility, or systematic risk, of a security or a portfolio in comparison to the market as a whole.</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="num">0.674</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Volume
        <div class="tooltip">
            <h3>Volume</h3>
            <p>The number of shares or contracts traded in a security or an entire market during a given period of time.</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="num" id="quoteVolume">1,513,740.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Div &amp; Yield
        <div class="tooltip">
            <h3>Dividend / Dividend Yield</h3>
            <p>A dividend is a distribution of a portion of a company's earnings, decided by the board of directors, to a class of its shareholders. Dividends can be issued as cash payments, as shares of stock, or other property. A dividend yield indicates how much a company pays out in dividends each year relative to its share price.</p>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="num">3.60/2.56% </td>
</tr>
```

This is what my code looks like right now.

```
#Importing Packages
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#Asking For Company's Stock Market Ticker
Ticker = input("Enter the Company's Ticker:")
#Adding The Ticker To The Website Search URL
my_url = 'https://www.investopedia.com/markets/stocks/' + Ticker + "/"

#Opening Up Connection, Grabbing The Page And Inputting "my_url" Variable
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#Parsing the HTML Code
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Finding The Company Name
company_name = page_soup.find("span", {"id": "quoteName"})
#Converting The Company Name To Text Without HTML
print(company_name.text)

#Finding The Company's Price Per Share
share_cost = page_soup.find("td", {"class": "value-price"})
#Converting The Share Cost To Just The Number Without HTML
print("Price Per Share: $" + share_cost.text.strip())

#Finding The Share's Daily Change
share_change = page_soup.find("span", {"id": "quoteChange"})
#Converting The Rate of Change To Just The Number Without HTML
print("Daily Rate of Change: $" + share_change.text.strip())

share_dividend_yield = page_soup.find("table", {"class": "name-value-pair hide-for-960"})
print(share_dividend_yield)
```

I tried modifying the print(share_dividend_yield) with ".tr.td.div.h3.p" at the end of yield before the parenthesis to get down to the line that I wanted and it won't let me go further than h3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry, if my post wasn't formatted properly, and thanks for taking the time to read my post!

Comment: can you give an example (or maybe couple) of `Ticker`?

Comment: Oh, that's just the company's letters that they are identified by on the stock exchange. So, like UNIT is Uniti Group Inc, JNJ is Johnson & Johnson. So, the user types the Stock Ticker that they want and then it goes to that URL for the company and scrapes the data.

Comment: Can't figure out what data you need. Can you please specify what exactly indicator do you want, which you can't collect?

Comment: At the bottom where it says "<h3>Dividend / Dividend Yield</h3>" four lines below that it says "<td class="num">3.60/2.56% </td>" this is the data that I'm trying to get. 

I tried doing "share_dividend_yield = page_soup.find("td", {"class": "num"})" but it's giving me the data from the top just below <h3>Beta</h3>. 

I also tried to go down to the "<td class="num">3.60/2.56% </td>" using extensions attached to "print(share_dividend_yield)" such as "print(share_dividend_yield.tr.td.div.h3.p)" to make my way down to the data all the way at the bottom, but it wouldn't let me do that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need a number that comes after "Dividend / Dividend Yield" phrase.
If so, then you can do something like this:

```
...(your code above)...
share_dividend_yield = page_soup.find("table", {"class": "name-value-pair hide-for-960"})

tds = share_dividend_yield.find_all('td')

for i in tds:
    if 'Dividend' in i.text:
        print(i.find_next('td').text)
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you so much! I don't understand why that works yet, I'll have to study more, but I really appreciate it!

Comment: no problem, glad to help.
Logic here is pretty simple, but if you face difficulties whth understanding the flow, let me know=)